# Change text size in Firemonkey StringGrid

Tags: delphi, header, firemonkey, tstringgrid

How to change text size in stringgrid header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write an [`OnApplyStyleLookup`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Types.TControl.OnApplyStyleLookup) event handler similar to this:

```
procedure TForm1.StringGrid1ApplyStyleLookup(Sender: TObject);
var
  Header: THeader;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Header := THeader((Sender as TStringGrid).FindStyleResource('header'));
  if Assigned(Header) then
  begin
    for I := 0 to Header.Count - 1 do
      with Header.Items[I].Font do
      begin
        Size := 32;
        Style := [TFontStyle.fsBold];
      end;
    Header.Height := 48;
  end;
  TStringGrid(Sender).Realign;
end;
```