# How to change font size at StringGrid in FM2

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

How can I change font size in StringGrid in rad studio XE3 - FM2 Firemonkey 2 not firemonkey 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
StringGrid1.StyledSettings.Size := False;
StringGrid1.TextSettings.Font.Size := 18;
```

This works fine on FireMonkey XE6,
But the script that you've reported, regarding the theader, does not work on XE6

Answer (score 2):

I searched internet and it seems that there is no way to resize text into **StringGrid**.

You can resize header using **FindStyleResource('header')**:

[Change text size in Firemonkey StringGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433934/change-text-size-in-firemonkey-stringgrid)

but it is not clear what to use (if any) instead of '***header***' so you can change text in the rows. Delphi help files are not useful at all as I cannot find all available parameters that I can use in **FindStyleResource** function.

As for the answer below:

**StringGrid1**.*Cells*[X,Y] do not  have a **StyleLookup** property.

Also, a some people suggested to use **OnDrawCell** procedure but again it looks like **StringGrid** is missing this (at least in *Delphi XE3 Firemonkey*).

Answer (score 0):

They still don't appear to have made this easy .

The cells are basically TEdits, hence they use the EditStyle for styling. But if you change that you'll change all TEdits. Not what you want.

Ideally there would be a 'CellStyleLookup' property. Set that, modify the style and off you go. But there isn't.

Comment: What problems are you having with it? (I've added an override directive which should have been there and may have caused your problem).

Comment: procedure TFontStringGrid.CreateCellControl: TStyledControl;(it must be function not procudere) - result not defined - where should i write this code

Comment: Yes, sorry, it needs to be a function. You need to create a child component of TStringGrid, as shown in the answer. You can register it on the component palette in the standard way if you want to use it in the designer.

Comment: have you ever check your code in xe 3? could you send write here your code

Comment: please someone send an example file to change stringgrid font size in radstudio xe 3- FM2

Comment: Have you tried the code I gave above? What results did you get?

Comment: On another look, I've removed the CreateCellControl stuff and shown code for iterating the columns and rows.