# Change THeader font size in FMX TStringGrid

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7, tstringgrid

I've searched this question and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433934/change-text-size-in-firemonkey-stringgrid).

so, I wrote a OnApplyStyleLookup event handler like this:

```
procedure TForm1.StringGrid1ApplyStyleLookup(Sender: TObject);
var
  Header: THeader;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Header := THeader((Sender as TStringGrid).FindStyleResource('header'));
  if Assigned(Header) then
  begin
    for I := 0 to Header.Count - 1 do
      with Header.Items[I].Font do
      begin
        Header.Items[I].TextSettings.HorzAlign := TTextAlign.Center;
        Size := 100;
        Style := [TFontStyle.fsBold];
//        SetSettings('Arial', 100, [TFontStyle.fsBold]);
      end;
    Header.Height := 48;
  end;
//  TStringGrid(Sender).Realign;
end;
```

text align is changed, but font size and style are not applied.

I'm using XE7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For apply changed text style, you must set [StyledSettings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FMX.Types.TStyledSettings) property for changed object.
So, final code looks like this (i dont like `with` operator)

```
procedure TForm1.StringGrid1ApplyStyleLookup(Sender: TObject);
var
  Header: THeader;
  HeaderItem: THeaderItem;
  I: Integer;
begin
  Header := THeader((Sender as TStringGrid).FindStyleResource('header'));
  if Assigned(Header) then
    begin
      for I := 0 to Header.Count - 1 do
        begin
          HeaderItem := Header.Items[I];

          HeaderItem.Font.Size := 100;
          HeaderItem.Font.Style := [TFontStyle.fsBold];
          HeaderItem.TextSettings.HorzAlign := TTextAlign.Center;
          // new code line:
          HeaderItem.StyledSettings := HeaderItem.StyledSettings - [TStyledSetting.Size, TStyledSetting.Style];
        end;
      Header.Height := 48;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: that's exactly what I want! really appreciate it!